# How to define Flask-SQLAlchemy(MySQL) hybrid propery or aggregated attributes for DateTime comparison

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For example there is Task (parent) object in database and Study objects (children). Study objects have start and finish time properties. How to define two hybrid properties for Task object. One for the earliest start time among its' tasks and another one for the latest finish time among its' tasks.

In documentation it says aggregated attributes or hybrid properties can be used for defining those earliest / latest attributes but I couldn't manage how to compare sa.DateTime objects and how to write those sql queries for these.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.sql import func as safunc

sa=SQLAlchemy()


class Task(sa.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tasks"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    studies = sa.relationship("Study", backref="task", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")

    @hybrid_propery
    def start(self):
        # ???

    @start.expression
    def start(cls):
        # ???

    @hybrid_propery
    def last_progress(self):
        # ???

    @last_progress.expression
    def last_progress(cls):
        # ???


class Study(sa.Model):
    __tablename__ = "studies"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("tasks.id"))
    start = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, server_default=safunc.now())
    finish = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, nullable=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it
Using python min/max method in hybrid property and min/max funcs in sqlalchemy.sql.func in property expression, code is working fine.

`task = Task.query.filter_by(id=id).first()`

`task.start` query returns the earliest study starting record and `task.last_progress` returns the latest study finish time for that task as I've looked for.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.sql import func as safunc

sa=SQLAlchemy()


class Task(sa.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tasks"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    studies = sa.relationship("Study", backref="task", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")

    @hybrid_propery
    def start(self):
        if any(i.start for i in self.studies):
            return min(filter(lambda x: x, [i.start for i in self.studies]))
        else:
            return None

    @start.expression
    def start(cls):
        return select([safunc.min(Study.start)]).\
                where(Study.task_id==cls.id).\
                label("start")

    @hybrid_propery
    def last_progress(self):
        if any(i.finish for i in self.studies):
            return max(filter(lambda x: x, [i.finish for i in self.studies]))
        else:
            return None

    @last_progress.expression
    def last_progress(cls):
        return select([safunc.max(Study.finish)]).\
                where(Study.task_id==cls.id).\
                label("last_progress")


class Study(sa.Model):
    __tablename__ = "studies"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("tasks.id"))
    start = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, server_default=safunc.now())
    finish = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, nullable=True)
```